# Javascript: how to calculate the beginning of a day with milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, date, time, milliseconds

i want to figure out the time from the beginning of the day given a days milliseconds.

so say i'm given this: 1340323100024 which is like mid day of 6/21/2012. now i want the milliseconds from the beginning of the day, which would be 1340262000000 (at least i think that's what it's supposed to be.)

how do i get 1340262000000 from 1340323100024?

i tried doing

```
Math.floor(1340323100024/86400000) * 86400000
```

but that gives me 1340236800000, which if i create a date object out of it, says its the 20th.

i know i can create a date object from 1340323100024, then get the month, year, and date, to create a new object which would give me 1340262000000, but i find it ridiculous i can't figure out something so simple.

any help would be appreciated.

btw, i'm doing this in javascript if it makes any difference.

Comment: That is going to be timezone-dependent.

Comment: You *know* how to do it, but you don't want to because you "find it ridiculous"? I think you should do what you just described! Date and time work is a pretty tricky subject, especially when jumping between timestamps and real time. Use the built-in functionality as much as possible!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with Thilo (localized to time zone), but I'd probably tackle it like this:

```
// Original: Thu Jun 21 2012 19:58:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
var ms = 1340323100024;
var msPerDay = 86400 * 1000;
var beginning = ms - (ms % msPerDay);
// Result:    Wed Jun 20 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
Number.prototype.StartOfDayMilliseconds = function(){
  return this - (this % (86400 * 1000));
}

var ms = 1340323100024;
alert(ms.StartOfDayMilliseconds());
```

**EDIT**

If you're particular about the timezone, you can use:

```
// Original: Thu Jun 21 2012 19:58:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
var ms = 1340323100024;
var msPerDay = 86400 * 1000;
var beginning = ms - (ms % msPerDay);
    beginning += ((new Date).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
// Result:    Thu Jun 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Notice that the offset is now removed so the 8pm the previous day turns in to midnight of the actual day on the timestamp. You can also probably (depending on implementation) do the addition before or after you modulo for the beginning of the day--your preference.

Comment: Trying to work out a way to exclude timezone, so hold on a sec... ;p

Comment: i didn't even think about that.. but i tested it with the various milliseconds i was working with and it worked.

Comment: @conman: FWIW, I got a version up that takes in to account timezone. ;-)

Comment: you are ficken awesome! i am so looking more into that to fully understand it. but yeah, looks like Thilo is right, it does get pretty ticky. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.toISOString().split("T")[0];
var date_ms = new Date(date).getTime();
```

or one line answer

```
console.log(new Date(new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]).getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(new Date(yourMilliseconds).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)).getTime();
```

Answer (score -4):

Actually, it should be `(currTimeMilli - 18000000) % 864000000` to get the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the day for GMT+5.