# Run a counter that is displayed on website

Tags: javascript, counter, backend

I want to run a counter on the back end of a website, so that it is constantly counting. I made a javascript counter (http://directinvent.com/counter/) which displays the desired result, although this resets whenever the site is loaded for each individual user.

The idea is simple enough. Run the counter back end and display the result live on front end. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: you could always store the value of the counter in a database or if you want it per user on localStorage but you need to know that the user can always clear the localStorage (it's frontend)

Comment: If you want a global value, how about mapping with the unix timestamp with some random? Everyone will see a very similar value and always counting.

Comment: I did that initially, but as you said it could lead to issues in regards to clearing the localStorage. Also I would like for it to count indefinitely, and it shouldn`t show a different count depending on the different user. Idk if that made any sense..

Comment: @spicydog That could also work, although I think a backend solution would work best, using cronjobs or similar to run the count function and then displaying the counter with javascript. Perhaps a solution can be running an update with cronjobs every minute and then running the javascript counter as displayed on the website, fetching the counter value on pageload?

Comment: What is it counting ? At what frequency?

Comment: @AxelH Its counting total loss over time. Basically with an increment of 3 per second. Very straight forward.

Comment: If this is a linear counter (same inc over time), just store the `starttime` for each user. Like a timer would do. Then, when you receive a request for the value, just need to calculate it `(currentTimeInSec - storeTimeInSec) * incrementationPerSec` No need of a running thread doing the count for everyone. This is how you create a timer in every langage, no with a `thread.sleep(x); inc();` because this loose precision quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this simply by getting the time of the day with the Date() variable, and multiplying the time of the day by the incremental constant desired. This way the scheme will automatically update every day with the correct number as wanted and all the users will be displayed the correct number at any given time.

```
    function dotimer()

    {

    today=new Date()

    window.setInterval("dotimer()",speed)

    testMilli = today.getMilliseconds()
    testSeconds = today.getSeconds()
    testMinutes = today.getMinutes()
    testHours = today.getHours()

    totalCost = Math.round(testHours * 10800 + testMinutes * 180 + testSeconds * 3 + testMilli * 0.003);

    document.getElementById("counterSeconds").innerHTML = totalCost;

    }
```

Although this works for this purpose, it still manages to freeze the browser, so I will have to work out a way to handle this...

Comment: This doesn't answer your own question `although this resets whenever the site is loaded for each individual user.` Since you didn't tell that you just need to start the counter at midnight, there were already solution for that ... [this will give you the milliseconds for a day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149555/javascript-how-to-calculate-the-beginning-of-a-day-with-milliseconds). Your solution is over complicated

Comment: PS : Don't use setInterval, call setTimeout at the end of this function, you will end up with infinte call like this !

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would do a Timer in Javascript. You store when you start your counter. Then you recalulate the result on every update (request). No need to do the math every 1/10s. If nobody ask, this is useless.

Basicly, this will look like this :

```
long startTime = storeTimeFor(User);
return (currentTimeInSec - startTimeInSec) * incrementationPerSec
```

With this, you only need to store the startTime for each user (in database, file, or in cache if you want). On reset, just store the currentTime again.

This is how you would do a timer in lots of langage because incrementing a value every seconds (using a sleep(1000)) would not be precise since your thread will not be running all the time, your are not alone on the machine ;)

## EDIT :

On the client side, I would not call to much the server, just ask the value store and do the math from the client with the same logic. Using a timeout to do the math over and over every X ms. See how to create a timer in Javascript if need, only the value calculate would change here.

Comment: Sweet! I will try this out! Thanks Axel!

Answer (score 0):

The counter must be stored in the backend (in file or database), either it is a single counter or one counter per user.

When rendering the page, initially show the counter that is read from the backend.

**If the speed of the counter is known and constant** (e.g. increase 3 per second), then you can use javascript (`setTimeout`) to increase it every second. The backend will store a number and the time (unix time) when it was created, e.g. 120 at 08:00:00. If a user access the website at 09:00:15, you know that it is 3615 seconds later, so you render the initial page showing the starting counter as 120 + (3615/3) = 1325. After that, the javascript will increment and display it by 3 per second.

**If the speed of the counter is unknown**, then you need to periodically (e.g. once per 10 seconds) check to the backend via ajax, requesting the current value of the counter. You can immediatelly display that latest value (which means the counter will be updated once every 10 seconds). **Or**, if you want to give a sense of "live", you can display it incrementally with animation on the client side.
Example: current display shows 120. Ten seconds later, via ajax request you get a new value 150. The difference is 150-120 = 30 in 10 seconds. You can display the counter increased by 3 per second (120, 123, 126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144, 147, 150). You can also play with random increment to be more realistic, as long as the total increment is 30 in 10 seconds.

Comment: This might actually be a very good way of doing it. Although it is unclear to me how I can run this counter in the backend. The best result would be if I store a single counter in the backend and display the counter value to the individual user, but the counter needs to increment somehow, and this is where I stumble upon my problems. If I show the counter that is read from the backend and never store new values to this counter, then it will basically appear static for the individual users.

Comment: can you clarify, what counter is it? how do you get the counter number? is it constant based on time, or based on how many visitors, or based on market price (which you get from some source)?

Comment: Its based on calculations we have made internally. So every day it will reset as a "How much has been lost today" feature. It should start from 0 and increment with 3 every second, that is it. No more hazzle.